# Das sprichwörtliche Tüpfelchen auf dem i

Tags: translation

Was bedeutet folgende Phrase?

> das sprichwörtliche Tüpfelchen auf dem i

Answer (score 3):

Das `i-Tüpfelchen` wird gerne als Redewendung verwendet, um besonders feine Details herauszuheben.

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/i_Tuepfelchen) definiert `i-Tüpfelchen` unter anderem als `Zutat, die einer Sache noch die letzte Abrundung gibt`.

Zum Beispiel:

> Jeder Ton passt bis aufs i-Tüpfelchen.

Bedeutet so viel wie `Jeder Ton wurde perfekt getroffen; es war bis ins kleinste Detail perfekt.`

Comment: Du hast in der Interpretation natürlich recht, aber interessanterweise *könnte* man das *bis auf* auch als *außer* lesen, z. B.: Es war alles gut vorbereitet, bis auf das Essen (= abgesehen vom Essen).

Answer (score 2):

Vgl. En. "to cross the t's and dot the i's" -- *einer Sache den letzten Schliff geben*; Sicherlich in Bezug auf Schreibschrift, in der die I-Punkte für ein Wort eben erst nach allen einfach verbundenen Strichen gesetzt werden.

Comment: "Schreischrift" ist aber ein hübscher Toppfehler ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Im Englischen gibt es einen ähnlichen Ausdruck:

> to a T

in Perfektion.

Beide Redensarten sind sehr ähnlich, wobei der Englische Ausdruck für Vollständigkeit steht, während die Deutsche Redensart

> bis auf das I-Tüpfelchen

darüber hinausgeht und dem Ganzen noch ein (ebenfalls sprichwörtliches) "Sahnehäubchen" aufsetzt.

Answer (score 0):

Irgendetwas zu beenden, fertig zu machen.

Wenn du ein "i" schreibst, schreibst du das punkt Markup am Ende.

Comment: Was soll _„[...] schreibst du das punkt Markup am Ende“_ heißen?